# Why the new apply() has been invented instead of modifying the commit() behavior?

Tags: android

Reading the docs on [SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) my understanding is that `apply()` acts exactly the same as `commit()` but adds an optimization to the algorithm to prevent ANR and such.

The docs explicitly stay it is safe to replace `commit()` with `apply()` and the lint encourages us to do so.

So the question is why they have devised the `apply()` and haven't modified `commit()`  instead?

Comment: @DerGolem I don't think this is correct. For backward compatibility, modifying `commit` would be a better approach.

Comment: I suggest you look at the differences in the source code between the two methods and see if there's anything that stands out.

Comment: @AleksG Good point. So, now I'm curious too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is why they have devised the apply() and haven't modified commit() instead?

`commit()` returns a `boolean`. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29), that `boolean` is:

> true if the new values were successfully written to persistent storage.

If `commit()` were modified to be asynchronous, then it cannot return a `boolean` to indicate a successful write operation, because at the point the value is returned, the write status is not yet known.

At the same time, they cannot modify `commit()` to return `void` or some `Future` thing or something, because that would break binary compatibility with apps that were written thinking that `commit()` would return a `boolean`. Existing apps working with the existing `commit()` would fail with a `VerifyError` or the equivalent when trying to call a `commit()` with a non-`boolean` return value.

Furthermore, Java does not allow you to have two methods with the same name and different return values. So they could not have two versions of `commit()`, unless they artificially added a parameter or something.

Hence, they created `apply()`.

Comment: With apply() then is there no way to understand if "new values were successfully written to persistent storage.", so, in a sense, using apply() is dangerous?
Seeing what they did in apply() one may argue that they could modify commit() instead to always return true.

Comment: @Alex: "using apply() is dangerous?" -- since it is just an XML file, it is rather unlikely to fail if the update is written well, but it *could* fail (e.g,. out of disk space). You would need to examine the implementation of `commit()` to see the precise circumstances under which `commit()` returns `false`. "they could modify commit() to always return true" -- you are welcome to your opinion, just as the Android engineers are welcome to theirs.

Comment: It seems, if one uses apply() and somehow apply() fails to store the value then the value is lost forever and the application's state is thus undefined. I surely understand it never happens in reality but still very strange

Comment: @Alex: "then the value is lost forever and the application's state is thus undefined" -- agreed. You are welcome to fork a thread and use `commit()`, if this concerns you. Or, switch to a different data storage engine (e.g., SQLite, with better transactional characteristics).